# NAV 2 - Human following with stereo camera

Tags: navigation, ros-humble, nav2

I try to implement [human following behavior using NAV 2](https://navigation.ros.org/tutorials/docs/navigation2_dynamic_point_following.html) with a differential drive controller, non-holonomic robot. My robot must be able to keep up even at higher speeds (human moving at 3m/s for example). I observe that theta values are always small. The issue is that human quickly disappears from the field of view of the camera and so robot stops. I would like to encourage sharp turn over smooth slopes. Should I change the controller ?

Notice that, for now, I don't use any obstacles detection method and the expected behavior is consequently as simple as always having the human to follow at the center of the camera. Of course, I would eventually integrate obstacles detection and that's why I want to integrate it with nav 2.

Here is the configuration file I use for now :

```
bt_navigator:
  ros__parameters:
    global_frame: map
    robot_base_frame: base_link
    odom_topic: /odometry/filtered_map
    default_nav_to_pose_bt_xml: $(find-pkg-share otto_navigation)/behavior_tree/follow_point.xml
    bt_loop_duration: 10
    default_server_timeout: 20
    plugin_lib_names:
    - nav2_compute_path_to_pose_action_bt_node
    - nav2_compute_path_through_poses_action_bt_node
    - nav2_follow_path_action_bt_node
    - nav2_back_up_action_bt_node
    - nav2_spin_action_bt_node
    - nav2_wait_action_bt_node
    - nav2_clear_costmap_service_bt_node
    - nav2_drive_on_heading_bt_node
    - nav2_is_stuck_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_goal_reached_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_goal_updated_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_initial_pose_received_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_reinitialize_global_localization_service_bt_node
    - nav2_rate_controller_bt_node
    - nav2_distance_controller_bt_node
    - nav2_speed_controller_bt_node
    - nav2_truncate_path_action_bt_node
    - nav2_goal_updater_node_bt_node
    - nav2_recovery_node_bt_node
    - nav2_pipeline_sequence_bt_node
    - nav2_round_robin_node_bt_node
    - nav2_transform_available_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_time_expired_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_distance_traveled_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_single_trigger_bt_node
    - nav2_is_battery_low_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_navigate_through_poses_action_bt_node
    - nav2_navigate_to_pose_action_bt_node
    - nav2_remove_passed_goals_action_bt_node
    - nav2_planner_selector_bt_node
    - nav2_controller_selector_bt_node
    - nav2_goal_checker_selector_bt_node

controller_server:
  ros__parameters:
    odom_topic: /odometry/filtered_odom
    controller_frequency: 10.0
    min_x_velocity_threshold: 0.001
    min_y_velocity_threshold: 0.5
    min_theta_velocity_threshold: 0.001
    debug_trajectory_details: true
    failure_tolerance: 0.3
    progress_checker_plugin: "progress_checker"
    goal_checker_plugins: ["goal_checker"]
    controller_plugins: ["FollowPath"]
    progress_checker:
      plugin: "nav2_controller::SimpleProgressChecker"
      required_movement_radius: 0.5
      movement_time_allowance: 10.0
    goal_checker:
      plugin: "nav2_controller::SimpleGoalChecker"
      xy_goal_tolerance: 0.5
      yaw_goal_tolerance: 0.1
      stateful: True
    FollowPath:
      # DWB Controller : https://navigation.ros.org/configuration/packages/dwb-params/controller.html
      plugin: "dwb_core::DWBLocalPlanner"
      critics: ["RotateToGoal", "Oscillation", "BaseObstacle", "GoalAlign", "PathAlign", "PathDist", "GoalDist"]
      BaseObstacle.scale: 0.02
      PathAlign.scale: 32.0
      PathAlign.forward_point_distance: 0.1
      GoalAlign.scale: 24.0
      GoalAlign.forward_point_distance: 0.1
      PathDist.scale: 32.0
      GoalDist.scale: 24.0
      RotateToGoal.scale: 32.0
      RotateToGoal.slowing_factor: 5.0
      RotateToGoal.lookahead_time: -1.0
      transform_tolerance: 0.2
      stateful: True
      short_circuit_trajectory_evaluation: true
      # Kinematic : https://navigation.ros.org/configuration/packages/dwb-params/kinematic.html
      max_vel_theta: 3.14
      min_speed_xy: -0.5
      max_speed_xy: 3.0
      min_speed_theta: -3.14
      min_vel_x: -0.5
      min_vel_y: 0.0
      max_vel_x: 3.0
      max_vel_y: 0.0
      acc_lim_x: 1.0
      acc_lim_y: 0.0
      acc_lim_theta: 2.0
      decel_lim_x: -10.0
      decel_lim_y: 0.0
      decel_lim_theta: -2.0
      # XYTheta Iterator : https://navigation.ros.org/configuration/packages/dwb-params/iterator.html
      vx_samples: 20
      vy_samples: 0
      vtheta_samples: 40
      # LimitedAccelGenerator : https://navigation.ros.org/configuration/packages/dwb-plugins/limited_accel_generator.html
      sim_time: 3.0 # it seems that a sim_time smaller than max speed will block the speed to this value
      # StandardTrajectoryGenerator : https://navigation.ros.org/configuration/packages/dwb-plugins/standard_traj_generator.html
      linear_granularity: 0.05
      forward_prune_distance: 10.0 # If small value, speed will be blocked
      angular_granularity: 0.025
      
local_costmap:
  local_costmap:
    ros__parameters:
      always_send_full_costmap: True
      update_frequency: 5.0
      publish_frequency: 2.0
      height: 10
      width: 10
      resolution: 0.05
      robot_base_frame: base_link
      robot_radius: 0.8
      rolling_window: true
      plugins: ["inflation_layer"]
      inflation_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::InflationLayer"
        cost_scaling_factor: 3.0
        inflation_radius: 0.55

# GPS WPF CHANGE: Set rolling global costmap with 50x50 size. See note below
global_costmap:
  global_costmap:
    ros__parameters:
      always_send_full_costmap: True
      update_frequency: 1.0
      publish_frequency: 1.0
      height: 50
      width: 50
      resolution: 0.1
      global_frame: map
      robot_base_frame: base_link
      robot_radius: 0.8
      # When using GPS navigation you will potentially traverse huge environments which are not practical to
      # fit on a big static costmap. Thus it is recommended to use a rolling global costmap large enough to 
      # contain each pair of successive waypoints. See: https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/issues/2174
      rolling_window: True     
      track_unknown_space: True 
      # no static map
      plugins: ["inflation_layer"]
      inflation_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::InflationLayer"
        cost_scaling_factor: 3.0
        inflation_radius: 0.55

planner_server:
  ros__parameters:
    expected_planner_frequency: 20.0
    planner_plugins: ['GridBased']
    GridBased:
      plugin: 'nav2_navfn_planner/NavfnPlanner'

waypoint_follower:
  ros__parameters:
    loop_rate: 200
    stop_on_failure: false
    waypoint_task_executor_plugin: "wait_at_waypoint"   
    wait_at_waypoint:
      plugin: "nav2_waypoint_follower::WaitAtWaypoint"
      enabled: True
      waypoint_pause_duration: 200

velocity_smoother:
  ros__parameters:
    smoothing_frequency: 20.0
    scale_velocities: false
    feedback: "OPEN_LOOP"
    max_velocity: [3.0, 0.0, 3.14]
    min_velocity: [-0.5, 0.0, -3.14]
    deadband_velocity: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
    velocity_timeout: 1.0
    max_accel: [1.0, 0.0, 2.0]
    max_decel: [-10.0, 0.0, -2.0]
    odom_topic: "odom"
    odom_duration: 0.1

behavior_server:
  ros__parameters:
    local_costmap_topic: local_costmap/costmap_raw
    local_footprint_topic: local_costmap/published_footprint
    global_costmap_topic: global_costmap/costmap_raw
    global_footprint_topic: global_costmap/published_footprint
    cycle_frequency: 10.0
    behavior_plugins: ["spin", "backup", "drive_on_heading", "wait", "assisted_teleop"]
    spin:
      plugin: "nav2_behaviors/Spin"
    backup:
      plugin: "nav2_behaviors/BackUp"
    drive_on_heading:
      plugin: "nav2_behaviors/DriveOnHeading"
    wait:
      plugin: "nav2_behaviors/Wait"
    assisted_teleop:
      plugin: "nav2_behaviors/AssistedTeleop"
    local_frame: odom
    global_frame: map
    robot_base_frame: base_link
    transform_timeout: 0.1
    simulate_ahead_time: 3.0
    max_rotational_vel: 2.0
    min_rotational_vel: 0.0
    rotational_acc_lim: 2.0
```

Thanks in advance for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

> The issue is that human quickly disappears from the field of view of the camera and so robot stops.

If you don't have sensors that can sense the human from a reasonable distance, that sounds like a problem.

> I would like to encourage sharp turn over smooth slopes. Should I change the controller ?

Sounds like some controller updates would be beneficial. Any application needs to have the algorithms tuned to their needs.

Comment: For your first point, I talk about disappearing from the horizontal field of view because the angular velocity isn't big enough. For your second point, how do you suggest I should proceed ? Take the base dwb planner implementation and fine tune it ? Any example I can follow ? Thanks for your answer

Comment: Interesting link for those wishing to set up their own controller : [nav2 doc](https://navigation.ros.org/plugin_tutorials/docs/writing_new_nav2controller_plugin.html).